# What are "tag" and "id" on Layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-logcat

I know how the switch statement works but I don't know what this means (R.id.webbutton). Can anyone please explain what it is and also what is TAG? 
Is there any guide for the beginners? I mean absolute beginners.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Id is id of your xml's components [may be views like textview,edittext... or viewgroup like linearlayout ,relativelayout... or anything else] in xml simply you can get reference to them in java code by saying

(R.id."id of your view in xml")

but firstly you should use setContentView(R.layout."name of xml file in layout/res in your project") 
this xml file which you want to use it's components .

TAG i use it when i want to show message in logcat [tool in eclipse you can watch your app messages when it is running] by saying String TAG= yourclassname.class.getsimpleName();

and use it in Log.d(TAG,"any string here"+some variable in my class i want to know it's value in a particular time when app running );

i hope that i made it clear to you .

Comment: why do you have to use the word TAG? why cant you use other names?

Comment: @Chaine it's just a convention

Answer (score 83):

[IDs and Tags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

**IDs**

> Views may have an integer id associated with them. These ids are
>   typically assigned in the layout XML files, and are used to find
>   specific views within the view tree. A common pattern is to:
>
> Define a Button in the layout file and assign it a unique ID.
>
> ```
> <Button
>    android:id="@+id/my_button"
>    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>    android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
> ```
>
> From the onCreate method of an Activity, find the Button
>
> ```
> Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
> ```
>
> View IDs need not be unique throughout the tree, but it is good
>   practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of
>   the tree you are searching.

**Tags**

> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially
>   an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They
>   are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in
>   the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate
>   structure.
>
> Tags may be specified with character sequence values in layout XML as either a single tag using the android:tag attribute or multiple tags using the  child element:
>
> ```
>  <View ...
>        android:tag="@string/mytag_value" />
>  <View ...>
>      <tag android:id="@+id/mytag"
>           android:value="@string/mytag_value" />
>  </View>
> ```
>
> Tags may also be specified with arbitrary objects from code using `setTag(Object)` or `setTag(int, Object)`.

Comment: Thanks for the that link. It explained most of my doubts.

Comment: If I put a tag in my layout as in those two examples in the Tags section above, how do I get the information out programmatically?

Comment: not sure what "tag" OP was asking about, but this answer helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html). (If you are so absolutely a beginner that you don't have a development environment set up yet, then start with [Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html).)

When you use the console log facility in Android, the first argument to the logging methods is a tag, which can be used to filter logcat output. A typical programming style is:

```
public class Something { 
    private static final String TAG = "Something";

    public void aMethod() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered aMethod");
    }
    . . .
}
```

That's what TAG is.

Resource IDs are explained in the tutorial. When you define a resource in XML, Android generates a class called `R` with nested classes for different kinds of resources (`R.id`, `R.string`, `R.layout`, etc.). Each of those nested classes has a constant for each resource of that type. `R.id.webbutton` might be generated from a layout file that has a button with attribute `android:id="@+id/webbutton"`. This is all explained in the tutorials.

Comment: I am reading the tutorials but I still find it a lot difficult to understand all of it. I know those tutorials are probably the best available but I think I need a few more weeks to go thorugh all of them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: a tag can be applied to an object with setTag and getTag

Comment: @matthewlent - Yes, but that's almost certainly different from the `TAG` (all upper case) that confused OP when it was encountered in code. A huge amount of Android sample code uses a `TAG` string constant when it shows anything being logging.

Comment: @TedHopp I think OP is asking about [view tags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Tags) not logging tags

Comment: @vlad - If that were the case, `TAG` wouldn't be all upper-case in the question. The all-upper-case `TAG` is usually seen in Android sample code, as well as in template code in Android Studio, as the logging tag (as I show in my answer). Also, since OP accepted Weloo's answer, which makes the same assumption I did, it's pretty clear that OP did **not** mean view tags.

Comment: @TedHopp you make a good point, I think you're right. I didn't even notice the capitalization at first and figured the question was in the context of views so it must be about view tags. My mistake.