# Difference between set/getId() and set/getTag()?

Tags: android, tags

I know that the base different is that `setId()` takes `int` as a parameter, while `setTag()` takes `Object`. I am asking more about practical advice.

When I generate more same elements programmatically, I set their IDs via `setId(++counter)` and that is fine for me to know which element has sent the `onClick` event. And I could do the same thing via `setTag(++counter)`, but I am used to the previous approach.

So when should I use `setTag()` and am I making a mistake when using `setId()`?

I guess if my way is right, then I'd use `setTag()` when I want to pass additional data, but I'll leave you comment on this issue first.

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view

Comment: Duplicate Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757069/what-are-tag-and-id-in-android

Comment: @vandzi seen it. it made me post this question. thanks

Comment: @userIsAMonkey not really a duplicate, but that's a great link, especially the 2nd answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guess is right. You should use the `setId()` when you only want a way to identify that particular `View` in your code and `setTag` when you want to pass additional information along with that `View`(that additional data may or may not uniquely identify that `View`).
You could use only the `setTag` method and pass a compound object that contains `id` + additional data but in this situation you are required to build a special object instead of the more simply way, calling the two methods in question.

**Edit :**
The docs for the [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class also contain valuable information about those two methods:

**IDs**

> Views may have an integer id associated with them. These ids are
>   typically assigned in the layout XML files, and are used to find
>   specific views within the view tree.

**Tags**

> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially
>   an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They
>   are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in
>   the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate
>   structure.

Answer (score 1):

`ID` is (typically unique) integer type of property which you can assign to any View just to recognize them in future.

`TAG` is `Object` type of property which is used to assign additional data (may by your own Object), different Object may carry similar tag.

So if you just want to uniquely identify your Views you should go with id (as it is primitive data type and will consume small amount of memory), whereas if you want your Object to carry additional info also, go with TAG.